# Plotting Pandas dataframe from pivot table, where index is the x-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot

I was trying to plot a graph from a dataframe that was created using pivoting a raw csv file. I tried to put the index "Month" as x-axis at the time of plotting using xticks

```
(ax = df.plot(xticks=df.index)
ylab = ax.set_ylabel('Device sold')
```

But everytime one error comes after executing the code:

```
f'units: {x!r}') from e matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: Index(['April', 'August', 'February', 'January', 'July', 'June', 'March', 'May'], dtype='object', name='Month')
```

The data where i tried to plot the above code is as below :

[image: [Pivoted data][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqq51.png]

Comment: How working `ax = df.plot()` ?

Comment: @jezrael, this is providing an output keeping index as x-axis as required but in y axis all others parameters are showing which is not demanding

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Provide a copy of the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe) as no one wants to recopy the data by hand.

Comment: `sample_data=pd.read_csv('Finance-REPORT-mProduct21-08-2019.csv')

Revenue=pd.pivot_table(sample_data,index="Month",values='Invoice Amount',aggfunc='sum')
Revenue = Revenue.reindex(Month_order).dropna()

df = pd.DataFrame(Revenue)
df.rename(columns={'Invoice Amount':'Total Revenue Earn (BDT)'}, inplace=True)
df2 = df.insert(1,"Total Online Payment (BDT) ",b,False)
.
.
.
df11 = df.insert(10,"Total Revenue Loss (BDT) ",k,False)
df12 = df.insert(11,"Total Successful Order",l,False)

ax = df.plot(xticks=df.index)
ylab = ax.set_ylabel('Device Sold')

Comment: Edit your question, and and the data there, not in a comment.